# Split different data (separated by a blank line) from a file in different lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, file, split

Python newbie here, I have a file which contains different physical experiment, divided by a blank line, as:

```
#t x
0 0
0 1
0 2

0 1
0 2
0 3
```

i would like to know if there is an easy way to split my data in multiple lists, based off column and experiment (list t1 for times of the first experiment, etc..), so that i can plot different experiments separately.

I tried with **numpy.loadtxt** and **pandas.read_csv** but they just skip over the blank lines and merge all the data. I searched for something like the c fscanf function that stops at a blank line but i couldn`t find an easy way.

Comment: You can read a text file line by line just as easily in Python as in c..  You asking a program designed to read well formatted csv files to read something else.

Comment: With `loadtxt`, it is possible to provide a list of lines instead of a filename.  Thus you could read the file, and pass groups of lines to a `loadtxt` call, getting back an array each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to split while reading the data, you can however read the whole file and take advantage of the blank lines to split the dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep=r'\s+', skip_blank_lines=False)

m = df.isna().all(axis=1)

dfs = [g for _,g in df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())]

print(dfs)
```

Output:

```
[    #t    x    # DataFrame #1
 0  0.0  0.0
 1  0.0  1.0
 2  0.0  2.0,
     #t    x    # DataFrame #2
 4  0.0  1.0
 5  0.0  2.0
 6  0.0  3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Read file
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    raw_data = f.read()

# Seperate each experiment
experiments = raw_data.split('\n\n')

# Split lines
experiments = [lines.split('\n') for lines in experiments]

# Create empty list for all.
all_data = []

for experiment in experiments:
    # Create empty list for each experiment.
    data = {'t':[], 'x':[]}
    for line in experiment:

        # if the first character of line is not a number, ignore ( for #t, x )
        if (not line[0].isdigit()): continue
        
        # split and convert data into int
        t, x = map(int,line.split(' '))

        # append it
        data['t'].append(t)
        data['x'].append(x)

    # append it
    all_data.append(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).